# Нужна ли запятая в сложном предложении такого типа?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "и резистор"? Не могу понять: является ли словосочетание "при отключении ввода 2СШ" объединяющим две части сложного предложения (и тогда запятая не нужна) или же тут все сложнее?

"К примеру, при отключении ввода 2СШ питание потребителей 2СШ осуществляется через секционную перемычку(,) и резистор, подключенный к 2СШ, необходимо отключать для сохранения селективности защит от ОЗЗ".